# Is there a way to put a navbar inside of a jumbotron?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Like I said in my question how should I do this
this is the the result I want
http://1drv.ms/1UKLEjg

The image is the background of a jumbotron
and the menu is in the jumbotron
can you help me please?
I can't share code because is from my work but is something like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>navbarTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body { padding-top: 70px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="top:15em; width=100%; margin-bottom:0;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse role="banner" style="margin-bottom:0;"">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a href="navbarTest.html" class="navbar-brand">Navbar Example</a>
                        </div>
                    <div class="navbar-text navbar-right">
                    <a href="navbarTest.html" class="navbar-link">
                        holaaa
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" href="C:\Users\alan.martinez.blanco\Downloads\jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post some code that you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just apply the jumbotron, make the navbar fixed at the top, and make it transparent, not sure if there is a whole lot more going on there.

so in that example, you can change the `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse role="banner" style="margin-bottom:0;"">` to `<nav class="navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse role="banner" style="margin-bottom:0;"">`

and then switch the jumbotron class from the div it is currently in to the `<body class = "jumbotron"` and then all you have to do is change the color and and opacity of the navbar itself.